# how to fix this issue with java 2d arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

Im trying to create a program that stores a name and an email from user input in an 2d array.

To further explain the purpose of this program, i must prompt the user for 2 option's either 0,1 or 5. 0 means end program. 1 means prompt the user for name and email and store in the 2d array and 5 is for printing out each pair of user info(i.e: name and email).  Problem with this code though, is that after the user types in the name and email it prints out the same pair of name and email 257 times. I want t the program to prompt for name and email and then reprompt user for an option.

effectively this is what im trying to create:

```
array = {{name, email}, and so on..}
```

for 256 times as it is the max number of users(or rolodex's) we can have.

Also, another problem with the code is that it fills up the rest of the array elements with the same name and email. I want it to prompt user every-time to type in a diffrent name and email pair and store it in the variable.

this is the code to my problem:

```java
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String[][] rolodex = new String[257][2];
System.out.println("Welcome!");
System.out.println("Please Select an option: ");
int choice = in.nextInt();
// in.nextLine();
while (choice != 0) {
    if (choice == 1) {
        System.out.println("Whats the name?");
        String name = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("What the email!");
        String email = in.nextLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < rolodex.length; i++) {
            rolodex[i][0] = name;
            rolodex[i][1] = email;
        }
    }
    if (choice == 5) {
        for (int i = 0; i < rolodex.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("email: " + rolodex[i][0]);
            System.out.println("name: " + rolodex[i][1]);
            System.out.println("--------------------");
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Please select an option: ");
    choice = in.nextInt();
    in.nextLine();
}
System.out.println("Thank you! Have a nice day!");
```

Problem with this code is it take in

Answer (score 0):

You need an additional variable to store the current position in the array. When you add an entry, it should be one time; not filling the entire array. Also, you could use a `do while` loop to reduce the repetitions in the code. Something like,

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
String[][] rolodex = new String[257][2];
System.out.println("Welcome!");
int choice;
int p = 0;
do {
    System.out.println("Please select an option: ");
    choice = in.nextInt();
    in.nextLine();
    if (choice == 1 && p < rolodex.length) {
        System.out.println("Whats the name?");
        rolodex[p][0] = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Whats the email?");
        rolodex[p][1] = in.nextLine();
        p++;
    } else if (choice == 5) {
        for (int i = 0; i < p; i++) {
            System.out.println("email: " + rolodex[i][1]); // email is [1]
            System.out.println("name: " + rolodex[i][0]);
            System.out.println("--------------------");
        }
    }
} while (choice != 0);

System.out.println("Thank you! Have a nice day!");
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I got your question I think it's better to use a Map instead of an 2d Array in your case like this:

```
Map<String, String> rolodex = new TreeMap<>();
```

With first String representing the email (because the key can't be duplicate) and second String standing for name.

Store in rolodex like this:

```
if (choice == 1){
    System.out.println("Whats the name?");
    String name = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("What the email!");
    String email = in.nextLine();
    rolodex.put(email, name);
}
```

Get data from rolodex like this:

```
if(choice == 5){
   for(String email: rolodex.keySet())
     System.out.println("email: " + email);
     System.out.println("name: " + rolodex.get(email));
     System.out.println("--------------------");
   }      
}
```

I am not quite sure how good you know Java but if Maps doesn't say you anything maybe watch a YouTube tutorial to better understand it :D